How to implement resilience4j circuit breaker with database connection unavailability along with @ControllerAdvice
My Service Class Code
@Autowired
private BookRepository bookRepository;

@CircuitBreaker(name = "backendA", fallbackMethod = "fallbackB")
public List<Book> findAll() {
    List<Book> bookList = new ArrayList<Book>();
    bookList = bookRepository.findAll();
    return bookList;
}

public String fallbackB(Throwable e) {
    //e.printStackTrace();
    System.out.println(" I Am within fallback method of BookController");
    return CIRCUITBREAKER_FALLBACK;
}

Controller Advice implementation
@ControllerAdvice
public class NotificationAdvisor {

    @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
    @ResponseBody
    public ErrorMessages handleException (final Exception ex) {
        
        System.out.println(" Exception within advice :: ");
        ex.printStackTrace();
        
        ErrorMessages errorMessage = new ErrorMessages();
        List<ErrorMessage> errorList = new ArrayList<ErrorMessage>();
         
        errorMessage.setErrorMessages(errorList);
        System.out.println(" Withing NotificationAdvisor !!"); 
        return errorMessage;
    }
}

POM dependency
<dependency>
            <groupId>io.github.resilience4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>resilience4j-spring-boot2</artifactId>
            <version>${resilience4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.github.resilience4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>resilience4j-circuitbreaker</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.1</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
        </dependency>

Now, application is working fine, but if database is down then , Circuitbreaker fallbackMethod = "fallbackB" is not called, but it is calling handleException method directly. This is only happening for database call , For Rest Call Circuit breaker is working as expected.
Could you please let me know if I am missing anything here to implement Circuit  breaker with Database unavailability.
Thanks in advance.

Perhaps the error is being thrown before it enters the controller? Try to debug it to see when is the error being thrown and what is the exception being thrown.
